# Can't get user stored in Express.js session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this code:

```
    app.post('/api/command', function (req, res, next) {
    var clientCommand = req.body.command;

    console.log("ClientCommand: ", clientCommand);
    if (!req.session.step || req.session.step === EMAIL) {

        // find user in db with email
        users.findOne({email: clientCommand}, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log("error: ", err);
            }
            console.log("result: ", result.email);

            // if user exists add user in session
            if (result != null) {
                req.session.user = result;
            }
        });//.catch(console.log);

        console.log("session outside: ", req.session.user);
        // change step to password
        req.session.step = PASSWORD;

    }
```

The problem is I want to access req.session.user outside users.findOne(...). But the output is:

```
ClientCommand:  example@gmail.com
session outside:  undefined
```

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. Also, I would like to know how express-session works and how it stores data in cookies (or on server-side).

Comment: i think you newer in node js. node js and it's all library is working on async method so you can't access outside of it's function.

Comment: yeah, I'm new to it, but as I understand session stores data in it, and I can access to it from anywhere in my code. I just could not find complete explanation to how session works.

Answer (score 0):

Findone is a async command due to which you are getting undefined.

Even if  you will notice 
"session outside:" is coming first
only after that "result: " console will come.

So if you have to move code inside findone or use custom middleware where you can execute query.

use this type of code in app js before calling routes

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    users.findOne({email: clientCommand}, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log("error: ", err);
            }
            console.log("result: ", result.email);

            // if user exists add user in session
            if (result != null) {
                req.session.user = result;
                next(); // After setting user ,  route will call 
            }else{
                next(); // will allow to go to route even if no user found
            }

        });//.catch(console.log);

})
```

if you want to call it  at particular url then use

app.use("[your url]",function(req,res,next){

Comment: I got this: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. What does this mean?

Comment: can you please add your app.js . Looks like you are adding it after routes